# Finding the n-th number that consists of only 2 or 3

Tags: python

I am really struggling with this program. I would appreciate any kind of help.
For a natural number we say that it is strange if it is completely composed of digits 2 and 3. The user enters a natural number. The program prints the n-th strange number.
Numbers that are considered strange are 2, 3, 22, 23, 33...

```
n = int(input())

current_number = 1
counter_strange = 0
counter = 0
while counter_strange < n:
    x = current_number
    while x < n:
        k = x % 10
        if k != 2 or k != 3:
            counter += 1
        else:
            break
    if counter >= 1:
        counter_strange += 1
    current_number += 1

print(current_number-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange numbers come in blocks. A block of 2 1-digit numbers, followed by a block of 4 2-digit numbers, then 8 3-digit numbers. You can do the math and determine which block of `k`-digit numbers a given index `n` is, and how far into that block it lies. Convert that distance into a base-2 number, zero-filled to `k` digits, then replace `0` by `2` and `1` by `3`. Convert the result back to an int:

```
from math import log2, ceil

def strange(n):
  """returns the nth strange number"""
  
  #first determine number of digits:
  k = ceil(log2(n+2)) - 1
  
  #determine how far is in the block of strange k-digit numbers
  d = n - (2**k - 1)

  #convert to base 2, zfilling to k digits:
  s = bin(d)[2:].zfill(k)

  #swap 2,3 for 0,1:
    
  s = s.replace('0','2').replace('1','3')

  #finally:
    
  return int(s)

for n in range(1,10): print(n,strange(n))
```

Output:

```
1 2
2 3
3 22
4 23
5 32
6 33
7 222
8 223
9 232
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop with `itertools.product` in a generator function. Using a generator will allow you to create a stream from which you can access strange numbers on the fly:

```
import itertools
def strange():
   c = 0
   while True:
      yield from map(''.join, itertools.product(*([['2', '3']]*(c:=c+1))))

s = strange()
for _ in range(10):
   print(int(next(s)))
```

Output:

```
2
3
22
23
32
33
222
223
232
233
```

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you. It is not as efficient as yours, of course, but a fairly straightforward alternative.